# SUPEE-11219 - Wrong Field Specified

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-11219

After installing SUPEE-11219, we can no longer save updates in System > Configuration > General > Design.

Whenever we click Save Config (even if not adding or changing and values) we receive the error "Wrong field specified".

We've tested commenting out `Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong field specified.'));` on line 413 of file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php` on a local testing site and this allows us to save changes.

We can't see any reason why `Wrong field specified` should be firing.

This is the actual logic triggering the error, maybe ther should be an if/else or else clause

```
if (($groupConfig ? !$groupConfig->dynamic_group : true) && !$this->_isValidField($fieldConfig)) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong field specified.'));
}
```

Comment: The issue has something to do with the Watermark settings.  These config paths are set dynamically, so they fail the field validation.  See `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Clone_Media_Image::getPrefixes()`

Comment: Which of the 2 checks is triggering it? `($groupConfig ? !$groupConfig->dynamic_group : true) && !$this->_isValidField($fieldConfig)`

Comment: It groupConfig empty for the specific  dynamic_group? Actually dont understand what is being verified here ... if  $groupConfig is empty ... then check if dynamic_group is a dynamic group and return false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our case, the issue occurred because we have some custom, dynamic fields in two system config groups. We solved it by adding the following tag to both of these groups in the system.xml:
`<dynamic_group>1</dynamic_group>`

So the final xml would look something like this:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <custom_group translate="label">
                    <label>Custom Group</label>
                    <sort_order>104</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <dynamic_group>1</dynamic_group>
                    <fields>
                        <some_dynamic_field translate="label">
                            ...
                        </some_dynamic_field>
                    </fields>
                </custom_group>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
   </sections>
</config>
```

This will tell Magento that the group contains dynamic fields, and will prevent the error from popping up when saving the config. Hope this will help someone!

Comment: Thank you. Adding `<dynamic_group>1</dynamic_group>` to Product Image Watermarks fixed this for us.

Comment: What were both the groups?

Comment: @snh_nl Can't remember exactly, but I believe for us both were custom groups which we added ourselves (so not from Magento or third party modules). I'm afraid you'll have to find out for yourself which groups/fields are causing the error in your case. If I remember correctly, in our case, it was because we had a field with a frontend model, which effectively created multiple fields based on some conditions. So maybe look for something like that within the xml of the section that is giving the error, and then adding the `dynamic_group` to the group(s) containing the dynamic field(s).

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe an improvement would also be that the error message is improved to demonstrate the field name and which validation is invalid. I really appreciate your reply thanks 